# Finding roots of the fourth degree polynomial: $2x^4 + 3x^3 - 11x^2 - 9x + 15 = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

My son is taking algebra and I'm a little rusty. Not using a calculator or the internet, how would you find the roots of $2x^4 + 3x^3 - 11x^2 - 9x + 15 = 0$. Please list step by step. Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 21):

Guessing one root sometimes opens up the whole equation for you.

First notice that $\displaystyle x=1$ gives 0. So $\displaystyle x-1$ is a factor.

Next, rewrite as

$\displaystyle 2x^4 - 2x^3 + 5x^3 - 5x^2 -6x^2 + 6x - 15x + 15$

This is to try and get $x-1$ as a factor.

This gives us

$\displaystyle 2x^3(x-1) + 5x^2(x-1) - 6x(x-1) - 15(x-1) = (x-1)(2x^3 + 5x^2 - 6x - 15)$

Now notice that $\displaystyle 2x^3 - 6x = 2x(x^2-3)$ and $5x^2 - 15 = 5(x^2 - 3)$

Thus

$\displaystyle (x-1)(2x^3 + 5x^2 - 6x - 15) = (x-1)(2x(x^2 - 3) + 5(x^2 - 3)) = (x-1)(x^2-3)(2x+5)$

and so the roots are $\displaystyle 1, \pm\sqrt{3}, -\frac{5}{2}$

Comment: If you're familiar with it, the process of "getting $x-1$ as a factor" can be done as polynomial long division: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division .  Personally I find this to be a bit cleaner than just mushing around the polynomial, even though of course they amount to exactly the same thing.

Comment: Note that what Moron did here is a very clever application of Horner's rule for dividing out linear factors.

Comment: You pretty much start with the rational root test: The roots are p/q where p=factor of 15, not necessarilty positive and q=factor of 2, same rules. Edit: The other user posted this.

Answer (score 9):

You can try first finding the rational roots using the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) in combination with the [factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) in order to reduce the degree of the polynomial until you get to a quadratic, which can be solved by means of the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula) or by [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

For example, to complement a little bit on Aryabhata's answer, the first solution he found $x = 1$ can be guessed by using the rational root theorem since the theorem tells you to look for rational solutions only in the set of fractions $\frac{\pm a}{b}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ are integers such that $a$ divides $15$ and $b$ divides $2$. Thus you list all divisors of $15$, which are $\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 15$ and the divisors of $2$ are $\pm 1, \pm 2$. then your list of possible rational roots would be $\pm \frac{1}{1}, \pm \frac{1}{2}, \pm \frac{3}{1}, \pm \frac{3}{2}, \pm \frac{5}{1}, \pm \frac{5}{2}, \pm \frac{15}{1}, \pm \frac{15}{2}$, and you have to start proving to see if any of those is a root of your polynomial.