# Factorise polynomial with real and complex roots

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, factoring, quartics

How would you go about finding the roots of the polynomial: 
$$x^4 +5x^3+4x^2+6x-4=0.$$

I attempt to form two quadratics e.g.
$$(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$
and then tried to expand, collect like terms, and solve for the coefficients simultaneously, but this results in a hard system of equations.

I was wondering if there was a better approach to this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rational Root Test? See: example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12787/finding-roots-of-the-fourth-degree-polynomial-2x4-3x3-11x2-9x-15

Comment: Not sure whether Kronecker's method or factoring modulo some primes gives a faster solution.

Comment: Maybe you try all the possible pairs of $b$ and $d$ multiplying to $-4$ ($b$ and $d$ must be integers). For every such pair, try to find $a$ and $c$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $x^4-4=(x^2+2)(x^2-2)$. This suggests that you might try to express your polynomial as$$(x^2+ax+2)(x^2+bx-2)=x^4+(a+b)x^3+abx^2+2(-a+b)x-4.$$It is now easy to see that all it takes is to choose $a=1$ and $b=4$.

Comment: I don't understand the initial remark. If you have $x^4+2x^2-5x-4$ then your suggestion is not very useful because the factorization is $(x^2+x+4)(x^2-x-1)$.

Comment: Indeed. But what I wrote here corresponds to the way I approached the problem. In this case, it worked. If it had not worked, then I might have tried [the general method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Factoring_quartic_polynomials).

Comment: Really? I think you were very lucky with your first approach.

Comment: Does this answer boil down to: "Assume there are nice integer coefficients somewhere: that make things easier to brute force."? In general, this is not so simple a task.

Comment: I tried it this way (after trying to find a rational root) and *in this specific case* it worked. It's not deeper than that.

Answer (score 4):

Since there are no rational roots (a rational root should be a divisor of $4$), your attempt of factorization as
$$x^4 +5x^3+4x^2+6x-4=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$
is a good idea.

Hint. By expanding the right-hand side and by comparing it with the the left-hand side, we have that $bd=-4$. Assuming that $b$ and $d$ are integers, by symmetry, you can try the following couples:
$$(b,d)\in\{(4,-1), (2,-2), (-4,1)\}$$
and then solve the corresponding systems with respect to the remaining coefficients $c$ and $d$.

P.S. If you are **lucky** you will start with the couple $(2,-2)$. Be careful though, there are polynomials, which are "similar" to the given one, such that the other couples work:

i) $(4,-1)$ for $x^4+2x^2-5x-4=(x^2+x+4)(x^2-x-1)$.

ii) $(-4,1)$ for $x^4-4x^2+5x-4=(x^2+x-4)(x^2-x+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

I like the following way.

For all real value of $k$ we have:

$$x^4+5x^3+4x^2+6x-4=\left(x^2+\frac{5}{2}x+k\right)^2-\left(\left(2k+\frac{9}{4}\right)x^2+(10k-6)x+k^2+4\right).$$
Now, we'll choose a value of $k$, for which $2k+\frac{9}{4}>0$ and $$(5k-3)^2-\left(2k+\frac{9}{4}\right)(k^2+4)=0.$$
Easy to see that $k=0$ is valid.

Thus,$$x^4+5x^3+4x^2+6x-4=\left(x^2+\frac{5}{2}x\right)^2-\left(\frac{9}{4}x^2-6x+4\right)=$$
$$=\left(x^2+\frac{5}{2}x\right)^2-\left(\frac{3}{2}x-2\right)^2=(x^2+x+2)(x^2+4x-2).$$
Can you end it now?